# Python Feature Engineer Movement Data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Hi I'm trying to feature engineer a Patient dataset from movement level to patient level.

Original df looks like this:

[image]

**Conditions:**
1) Create `Last Test<n> Change` cols - For `CaseNo` that encounters the `Category` value 'ICU', take the `Test<n>` change before 'ICU' value (189-180 for Test1, CaseNo 1), else take the latest `Test<n>` change (256-266 for Test1, CaseNo 2).
2) Create `Test<n>_Pattern` cols - For `CaseNo` that encounters the `Category` value 'ICU', pivot all the `Test<n>` values from start till before 'ICU' value. Else pivot all `Test<n>` values from start to end.
3)Create `Last Test<n> Count` cols - For `CaseNo` that encounters the `Category` value 'ICU', take the last `Test<n>` value before 'ICU' encounter. Else take the last `Test<n>` value.

**Expected Outcome**:

[image]

How do I go about this in Python?

**Code for df**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'CaseNo':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
                    'Movement_Sequence_No':[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4],
                    'Movement_Start_Date':['2020-02-09 22:17:00','2020-02-10 17:19:41','2020-02-17 08:04:19',
                                           '2020-02-18 11:22:52','2020-02-12 23:00:00','2020-02-24 10:26:35',
                                           '2020-03-03 17:50:00','2020-03-17 08:24:19'],
                    'Movement_End_Date':['2020-02-10 17:19:41','2020-02-17 08:04:19','2020-02-18 11:22:52',
                                         '2020-02-25 13:55:37','2020-02-24 10:26:35','2020-03-03 17:50:00',
                                         '2222-12-31 23:00:00','2020-03-18 18:50:00'],
                    'Category':['A','A','ICU','A','B','B','B','B'],
                    'RequestDate':['2020-02-10 16:00:00','2020-02-16 13:04:20','2020-02-18 07:11:11','2020-02-21 21:30:30',
                                   '2020-02-13 22:00:00','NA','2020-03-15 09:40:00','2020-03-18 15:10:10'],
                    'Test1':['180','189','190','188','328','NA','266','256'],
                    'Test2':['20','21','15','10','33','30','28','15'],
                    'Test3':['55','NA','65','70','58','64','68','58'],
                    'Age':['65','65','65','65','45','45','45','45']})
```

**Expected Outcome:**

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'CaseNo':[1, 2],
                    'Last Test1 Change':[9, -10],
                    'Test1 Pattern':['180, 189', '328, 266, 256'],
                    'Last Test1 Count':[189, 256],
                    'Last Test2 Change':[1, -13],
                    'Test2 Pattern':['20, 21', '33, 30, 28, 15'],
                    'Last Test2 Count':[21, 15],
                    'Last Test3 Change':[10, -10],
                    'Test3 Pattern':['55', '58, 64, 68, 58'],
                    'Last Test3 Count':[55, 58],
                    'Age':[65, 45]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try in this way:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'CaseNo':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
                    'Movement_Sequence_No':[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4],
                    'Movement_Start_Date':['2020-02-09 22:17:00','2020-02-10 17:19:41','2020-02-17 08:04:19',
                                           '2020-02-18 11:22:52','2020-02-12 23:00:00','2020-02-24 10:26:35',
                                           '2020-03-03 17:50:00','2020-03-17 08:24:19'],
                    'Movement_End_Date':['2020-02-10 17:19:41','2020-02-17 08:04:19','2020-02-18 11:22:52',
                                         '2020-02-25 13:55:37','2020-02-24 10:26:35','2020-03-03 17:50:00',
                                         '2222-12-31 23:00:00','2020-03-18 18:50:00'],
                    'Category':['A','A','ICU','A','B','B','B','B'],
                    'RequestDate':['2020-02-10 16:00:00','2020-02-16 13:04:20','2020-02-18 07:11:11','2020-02-21 21:30:30',
                                   '2020-02-13 22:00:00','NA','2020-03-15 09:40:00','2020-03-18 15:10:10'],
                    'Test1':['180','189','190','188','328','NA','266','256'],
                    'Test2':['20','21','15','10','33','30','28','15'],
                    'Test3':['55','NA','65','70','58','64','68','58'],
                    'Age':['65','65','65','65','45','45','45','45']})

# simple data management 
df = df.replace('NA', np.nan)
df[['Test1','Test2','Test3','Age']] = df[['Test1','Test2','Test3','Age']].astype(float)

# create empty df to store results
results = pd.DataFrame()

# split original df in groups based on CaseNo
for jj,(j,gr) in enumerate(df.groupby('CaseNo')):

    group = gr.copy()
    # idenfify the presence of ICU
    group['Category'] = (group['Category'].values == 'ICU').cumsum()
    # replace NaN value with the next useful value
    # this is useful to fill NaN in Test1, Test2, Test3
    group_fill = group.fillna(method='bfill')
    # select part of df before the first ICU matched
    group_fill = group_fill[group_fill.Category == 0]
    group = group[group.Category == 0]
    # at this point we have two copy of our group df (group and group_fill)
    # group contains the raw (inclused NaN) values for a selected CaseNo
    # group_fill contains the filled values for a selected CaseNo

    # create empty df to store partial results
    partial = pd.DataFrame()
    # select unique CaseNo
    partial['CaseNo'] = group['CaseNo'].unique()

    # for loop to make operation on Test1, Test2 and Test3
    for i in range(1,4):

        # these are simply the operation you required
        # NB: 'Last TestN Change' is computed on the group df without NaN
        # this is important to avoid errors when the last obsevarion is NaN
        # 'TestN Pattern' and 'Last TestN Count' can be computed on the filled group df
        partial[f'Last Test{i} Change'] = group_fill[f'Test{i}'].tail(2).diff().tail(1).values
        partial[f'Test{i} Pattern'] = [group[f'Test{i}'].dropna().to_list()]
        partial[f'Last Test{i} Count'] = group[f'Test{i}'].dropna().tail(1).values

    # select unique age
    partial['Age'] = group['Age'].unique()
    # create correct index for the final results
    partial.index = range(jj,jj+1)
    # append partial results to final results df
    results = results.append(partial)

# print final results df
results
```

[image]

Comment: cool. could u add some explanation/comments of your code pls. thx!

Comment: I added comments in the code... I remain at disposal

Comment: Nice code Marco, esp the ```.tail(2).diff().tail(1).values``` part. Prob need to thank @Henry Yik for ````group['Category'] = (group['Category'].values == 'ICU').cumsum()````. <br>

Final qn: why did u choose to use ````for jj,(j,gr) in enumerate(df.groupby('CaseNo')):````? My concern is on the computational efficiency. As I'll be applying this on a real dataset with hundreds of thousands of row... Why didn't you choose to convert df to a list and iterate, or use ````for jj,(j,gr) in (df.groupby('CaseNo').iterrows())````

Comment: tail(2) take the last 2 element, diff() make the diff on them, diff() with 2 number produce [NaN, float], we need the float/the last element, so tail(1) do the job. use cumsum with a complex hierarchical structure to respect some conditions is a good trick that you can find in a lot of situations. df.groupby('CaseNo').iterrows() is not possible... you can't compute iterrow on groupby. I understand what you say and I suggest you leave it as is because this does the job

Answer (score 2):

I am just gonna show you how to approach your problem in a general way.

For your first condition, you can create a helper index by `cumsum` to filter out the data after ICU:

```
df["helper"] = df.groupby("CaseNo")["Category"].transform(lambda d: d.eq("ICU").cumsum())
```

I am not really sure what `n` stands for, but if you just want to grab certain amount of data, use `groupby` and `tail`:

```
s = df.loc[df["helper"].eq(0)].groupby("CaseNo").tail(4).filter(regex="CaseNo|Test.*|Age")

print (s)

   CaseNo  Test1  Test2  Test3 Age
0       1  180.0   20.0   55.0  65
1       1  189.0   21.0    NaN  65
4       2  328.0   33.0   58.0  45
5       2    NaN   30.0   64.0  45
6       2  266.0   28.0   68.0  45
7       2  256.0   15.0   58.0  45
```

Finally `pivot` your data:

```
res =  (pd.pivot_table(s, index=["CaseNo", "Age"],
                       aggfunc=["last", list]).reset_index())

print (res)

  CaseNo Age   last                                    list                                                    
              Test1 Test2 Test3                       Test1                     Test2                     Test3
0      1  65  189.0  21.0  55.0              [180.0, 189.0]              [20.0, 21.0]               [55.0, nan]
1      2  45  256.0  15.0  58.0  [328.0, nan, 266.0, 256.0]  [33.0, 30.0, 28.0, 15.0]  [58.0, 64.0, 68.0, 58.0]
```

From here you can work towards your final goal.

Comment: n in `Test <n>` stands for test number in `Test1` col, `Test2` col, and `Test3` column respectively.